# Clipboard app which shows all

Tags: clipboard, copy-and-paste

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 LTS.

I've been installed 2 clipboard apps: Clipit and Clipman.

But, none of them shows all.

Let's say: when I copy some image, from any source, they don't show it. When I copy some midi notes, from any source, they don't show it. When I copy some multimedia data (audio and/or video), from any source, they don't show it. The only one thing both apps show is plain text. So...

Is there some clipboard app which shows all kind of material we are copying? Where?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not an app, I found this [Clipboard Inspector](https://evercoder.github.io/clipboard-inspector/) website ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/Evercoder/clipboard-inspector)) useful for investigating one off situations.

It enumerates the `types`, `items` and `files` that get pasted or drag-n-dropped into it.

Answer (score -1):

A *clipboard* by definition contains only text. What it sounds like you want is a screenshot tool. Any Ubuntu distro should have one pre-installed. In Ubuntu Studio 20.04 it's called "Screenshot" under Accessories.

Comment: This is not correct. A clipboard can contain text or binary objects.